# Possibly `undefined` property of parent object of an array in its `map` callback

Tags: arrays, typescript

I am attempting to `map` the values of an array, which is a property of an object, to another property of the same object.

The code below ([TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBA9gXBDeECGcB2BXAtgIxAJwG0BdAGgmzgGcw8BLVAcwgF8IAfCdVAExADN6IbhAC8CZHGJkKEAOSyWAbgBQyqAH4AdEk2YkABwAUhgJSiAfNE3YTioA)):

```
let o: { a: number[], b: string } | undefined = { a: [], b: '' };

o?.a.map(() => o.b);
```

Generates the error:

```
'o' is possibly 'undefined'.
```

when accessing `o.b` property in the `map` callback.

However, if `o` is `undefined` the `map` would prevented by the `?`. Therefore `o` can't theoretically be `undefined` in the callback.

Do you have any explanation for this behaviour ?

Comment: It’s [ms/TS#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998); see the q/a linked above for more information.

Comment: @jcalz Ok got it, thanks for pointing it out ! Should I delete this dupe though ?

Comment: Duplicate questions are actually helpful; other people searching might find this question and it will forward them to the answer.  So there's no reason to delete.